# Node.js class property not being populated after being set in the object

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have a class that is used to handle mysql connections. It has a function for creating a connection pool and one for running inserts. The problem is that when I attempt to run the insert with `pool.query` the function fails. The error it produces is:

```
  errorMessage: TypeError: Cannot read property 'pool' of undefined
```

It seems like the `this.pool` property is not defined before the `insert()` function is executed.

Why would the `pool` property be undefined when it was defined on the `conn.createPool` call?

Here is the Connection class:

```
const mysql2 = require('mysql2');

class Connection {
    constructor(options = {}) {
        this.options = options
    }

    createPool () {
        this.pool = mysql2.createPool({
            host: this.options.host,
            user: this.options.user,
            database:  'my-db',
            ssl: 'Amazon RDS',
            password: this.options.password,
            authPlugins: {
                mysql_clear_password: () => () => Buffer.from(this.options.password + '\0')
            }
        });
    }

    insert () {
        const promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

            try {
                let sql = "INSERT INTO included_network(field1, field2, field3, created_date, modified_date, created_by, modified_by) VALUES ?";
                let values = [
                    ['229', 'data1', 'moredata', Date.now(), Date.now(), 'service', 'service'],
                    ['608', 'data2','moredata', Date.now(), Date.now(), 'service', 'service'],
                    ['608', 'data3','moredata', Date.now(), Date.now(), 'service', 'service'],
                    ['673', 'data4','moredata', Date.now(), Date.now(), 'service', 'service'],
                ];

                this.pool.query(sql, [values],function (error, results, fields) {
                    if (error) throw error;
                    console.log(results.affectedRows); //Show 1
                    resolve (results.affectedRows);
                });
            } catch (e) {
                reject(e);
            }

        })
        return promise;
    }
}

module.exports = { Connection };
```

And here is the handler attempting to use the class to create a connection and execute an insert:

```
const utils = require('./utils');
const conns = require('./connection');


let response = {
  statusCode: 200,
  body: {
    message: 'SQS event processed.',
  },
};

exports.handler = async(event) => {
  try {
    const options = {
      host: 'aurora-proxy.proxy.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
      user: 'service'
    };

    const token = utils.getToken(options);
    options.password = token;

    const conn = new conns.Connection(options);
    conn.createPool();
    await conn.insert();
    
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('There was an error while processing', { errorMessage: e});

    response = {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: e
    }

  }

  return response;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `this` is undefined in the callback function in your promise—it does **not** point at the class instance.

Use an arrow function to get a lexically scoped `this` pointer (which is what you're expecting).

e.g.

```js
  insert() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // ...
    });
  }
```

Comment: How would I run multiple `insert` calls at the same time? I notice that I must now use `await` on the function call, but I'd rather run multiple inserts without waiting. Should I not use a Promise?

Comment: Do something like `await Promise.all([conn.insert(), conn.insert2(), conn.insert3()])`